# Text spills over onto custom <input type="text" white border

Tags: html, css

I've got a custom background for the element `<input type="text">`, however the text currently 'overlaps' it, meaning it spills over the outside when you type (which isn't meant to happen), as the image has a white border around it.

Here's a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dnf419y5/

Here's my code:

```css
 .maininput {
         background-image: url('http://questers.x10.mx/images/inputbox.png'); 
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         width: 418px; 
         height: 95px;
         border: 0px;
         outline: none;
         font-size: 20px;
        }
```

```html
        <form method="post">
        <input type="text" class="maininput" placeholder="text..">
        </form>
```

I attempted to add `padding: 10px` to the class `.maininput` and that solves the text spilling over onto the white border on the left, but not the text spilling over onto the right.

Comment: You could change the opactity of the text..

Comment: How in this context?

Comment: Yes.. And move the text to right..

Comment: No this is easy... just get it to opactity: 0.5;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to keep the text inside your background. You can calculate the width of your input like (your-background-width - (2 * padding)). For this example it's 418px - (2 * 30px).

```css
.maininput {
    background-image: url('http://questers.x10.mx/images/inputbox.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 358px; 
    height: 95px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="maininput" placeholder="text..">
</form>
```